# Moving a file from a windows Java application to a linux box

Tags: java, windows, linux, filesystems

I'm currently doing a project that has to be run on a windows machine. The application creates a CSV file and saves it to the windows filesystem. I would like a way to transfer this file to a machine running linux into a directory selected by the user.

I am not asking for code (although if it helps then feel free :P ) but asking more for what protocols to use (ftp etc) and wether I need to take anything into account such as permissions in Linux as I am fairly in experienced with programming for linux file systems.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can the windows machine see the linux filesystem? Is there a samba server running on the linux machine? If so, you can simply copy it from one filesystem to the other.

If not, you can try SCP or SFTP but you need to have the keys setup. Another way is to use `Runtime.exec` to copy the file using a windows specific command utility.

If all else fails, run a java process on the linux server and connect to it using [sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/). Your windows client can write the file to the socket and it can be written out by the linux server.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using SSH as SCP is a fairly standard and convenient way to transfer files securely.  In Java you can use jssh amoungst other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do it programatically, I'd suggest using [Rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). It should be available for most *nix distros and you've got a Windows version called [DeltaCopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) that implements the same protocol.